# CASE Statement - Batch

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Looking at making a basic scoring system based on questions answered.

The questions that are asked, all have 3 possible answers which are identical per question.

Currently I have:

```
SELECT [form].[Name],
       [form].[TimeTag1],
    (100 - [Form].[Field2] - [Form].[Field3] - [Form].[Field4] - [Form].[Field5]) AS [Total]
FROM
    (SELECT 
        af.Name
       ,af.TimeTag1
       ,CASE WHEN [af].[aField46] = 'Checked Ok' THEN CONVERT(INT, '0')
             WHEN [af].[aField46] = 'Rectified On-Site' THEN CONVERT(INT, '5')
             WHEN [af].[aField46] = 'Failed' THEN CONVERT(INT, '5')
        END AS [Field2]
       ,CASE WHEN [af].[aField2] = 'Checked Ok' THEN CONVERT(INT, '0')
             WHEN [af].[aField2] = 'Rectified On-Site' THEN CONVERT(INT, '5')
             WHEN [af].[aField2] = 'Failed' THEN CONVERT(INT, '5')
        END AS [Field3]
       ,CASE WHEN [af].[aField4] = 'Checked Ok' THEN CONVERT(INT, '0')
             WHEN [af].[aField4] = 'Rectified On-Site' THEN CONVERT(INT, '5')
             WHEN [af].[aField4] = 'Failed' THEN CONVERT(INT, '5')
        END AS [Field4]
       ,CASE WHEN [af].[aField5] = 'Checked Ok' THEN CONVERT(INT, '0')
             WHEN [af].[aField5] = 'Rectified On-Site' THEN CONVERT(INT, '5')
             WHEN [af].[aField5] = 'Failed' THEN CONVERT(INT, '5')
        END AS [Field5]

    FROM vAdvF_167 af) AS [Form]
```

This works but I'm looking for a more efficient way of completing this task as there will be over 100 potential questions which could be answered.

Is this the main way to achieve what I want or is there a quicker/more efficient way as this will be added to SSRS Reporting once done.

Edits:

- The Table cannot be changed.
- Those 3 answers are the only answers ever available to a user on all Q's

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: Do you intentionally return `5` for both `'Rectified On-Site'` and `'Failed'`? Also, why bother converting `CONVERT(INT, '5')` when you can write `5`?

Comment: Why are you using CONVERT(INT, '5') for each value instead of just the value (i.e Then 5)?  This in itself would make it more efficient I would think.

Comment: Are there any other values you can have in `FieldXYZ` in addition to `'Checked Ok'`, `'Rectified On-Site'`, and `'Failed'`?

Comment: Time to normalize? (Better to have 100 rows instead of 100 answer columns.)

Comment: @jarlh It's well past that time, I think. While at it, OP could replace string codes with numeric codes, making this whole query very short and readable.

Comment: can you modify the structure of your table?

Comment: Apologies, I should have explained where the data comes from.

This comes from an application which are all text values (NVARCHAR) in the DB Tables, which cannot be changed. I converted to an INT so I could do a SUM at the end so the scoring is calculated.

I intend to publish this data into a Report which users can run on the intranet which will show all users names and the scoring they have achieved per Form they submit. - - Also They are both intentionally 5, not a request from myself but this is a scoring system set by someone else..

Comment: So don't change the tables, but unpivot the desired columns in the query.  That way you have 1 case statement.

Comment: Do you need the output in the format answ2, answ3, ... answ100 as columns or you can modify your report to have a record for evey answer?

Comment: They always answer every question in the Form so they all need to be compared for results, so lets say there are 100 Questions - The output of the report will be 'Name' 'Address' 'Score'.  -  The Score will be auto calculated so the user will only see the score and not the questions answered. (Name and Address will be added to this when needed, it's just one extra field each)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's going to perform better, but a translation table will make the query more readable, at the very least:

```
DECLARE @Translate AS TABLE
(
    string varchar(17),
    number int
)
INSERT INTO @Translate VALUES
('Checked Ok', 0),
('Rectified On-Site', 5),
('Failed', 5)


SELECT [form].[Name],
       [form].[TimeTag1],
    (100 - [Form].[Field2] - [Form].[Field3] - [Form].[Field4] - [Form].[Field5]) AS [Total]
FROM
    (SELECT 
        af.Name
       ,af.TimeTag1
       ,f46.number AS [Field2]
       ,f2.number AS [Field3]
       ,f4.number AS [Field4]
       ,f5.number AS [Field5]

    FROM vAdvF_167 af
    JOIN @Translate f46 ON  [af].[aField46] = f46.string
    JOIN @Translate f2 ON  [af].[aField2] = f2.string
    JOIN @Translate f4 ON  [af].[aField4] = f4.string
    JOIN @Translate f5 ON  [af].[aField5] = f5.string) AS [Form]
```

Comment: FYI: you could even do it in a single statement: WITH Translate AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES --your values list--) t(string, number)) SELECT .... Just drop the @ from @Translate. (SQL Server allows VALUES in the FROM clause (http://modern-sql.com/feature/values)). WITH avoids the repetition (http://modern-sql.com/feature/with).

Comment: @markus correct. I don't know why I didn't think about a cte.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change table, one of the thing you can optimize (every) case in this way (e.g.) (It can help you to generate using information_schema):

```
,CASE WHEN [af].[aField46] = 'Checked Ok' THEN 0
      WHEN [af].[aField46] IN('Rectified On-Site', 'Failed' THEN 5
      END AS [Field2]
```

Comment: Yeah it makes sense to do it that way instead, thanks. - I thought there may  have been some smart way someone would have done in a SP or something haha.

Comment: @Benzz Function would be nicer looking of course, performance won't be better.